# How to simply checkout branch by owner:branch

Tags: git, github, branch, git-checkout

On github, I'm looking for a straight forward way how to checkout a branch from a pull request.

I can see a highlighted branch like `owner:branch`.

The `owner` leads to a fork of a repository. The `branch` is a branch in the forked repo.

Can I use this `owner:branch` to just copy it and paste in 1 line command?

Comment: The name of the repository is necessary. If you already know the name, as `foo`, `git fetch https://github.com/$owner/foo $branch:$branch && git checkout $branch`. You can make a small function.

Comment: Good idea, thx.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach would to use the [GitHub CLI `gh`](https://cli.github.com/manual/) and:
[`gh pr checkout`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_checkout)

```bash
// Checking out a pull request locally
~/Projects/my-project$ gh pr checkout 12
remote: Enumerating objects: 66, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (66/66), done.
remote: Total 83 (delta 66), reused 66 (delta 66), pack-reused 17
Unpacking objects: 100% (83/83), done.
From https://github.com/owner/repo
 * [new ref]             refs/pull/8896/head -> patch-2
M       README.md
Switched to branch 'patch-2'
```

In that case, all you need is the PR number, instead of relying on the owner and their fork repository name.